# Performance testing tool which supports OpenText Enterprise Information Management Application

Tags: software-testing, performance-analysis, ecm, performance-testing

We have a requirement for conducting performance test on OpenText EIM ( Content Server). What are the proven performance testing tools for testing OpentText EIM application?

**Objectives:**

1. Tool should be able to support the user load of 2000 concurrent users.
2. Preferably Open source.
3. Tool should be able to capture the traffic between OpenText EIM Client and Server without any issue.

Comment: I removed this off-topic part, please ask at superuser.com : `**Clarification:**

Does OpenText EIM also uses **a lightweight applet/ UCF Client** that is responsible for transferring content between the content server, application server and the client machine during operations such as check-in, checkout, import etc., like it does in the similar kind of application **(ECM Documentuem WebTop)** ?`

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Kindly help me by adding appropriate tags to my Question. I am not able to do the same as I don't have enough reputation points. The appropriate Tags would be as following: "Performance-Testing" "OpenText EIM Performance Testing" "OpenText ContentServer PT"

Comment: OK, I added the appropriate tags. Let's have a single "opentext" tag until we have many Opentext questions.